# Infinite loop channel operation cause high CPU usage

Tags: go, cpu, channel

the code example is as followed

```
var TestChan chan int    

func SendDataToChannel(dataIn int){
        select {
           case TestChan <- dataIn:
           return
        default:
          return
    }
}

func HandleChannelData(){

    for{
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
        tmpData := <- TestChan
        /*
        DoSomething with tmpData, call other server
        */
     }
}

func main(){
    TestChan = make(chan int)
    go HandleChannelData()
    ／*
        Start server
     *／
 }
```

The scenario is that, in my server, every request(3-5thousand qps) will call the SendDataToChannnel. DoSomething in HandleChannelData takes times to process and its downstream is under a QPS limitation, so I simply add a sleep in HandleChannelData.  The data add to the Channel should be non-bloacking and can be discarded, So I get a "select default" and non-buffered Channel there.

When the server runs, the CPU usage increase infinitely and finally reached 95%(4 cores) while I have to shutdown the server. I pprof the server get the torch graph, find nothing(same distribution to the same server without this channel logic )
I'm confused by the CPU usage.

Comment: SendDataToChannel should not have a default select case, it should block until it can send the data to the channel. Otherwise you either lose data or go through a busy loop.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer In my case，the SendDataIn should be non-blocking and the data can be discard， as I memtioned in the question

Comment: Seems like you are just feeding your server more work than it can handle, but your code doesn't demonstrate what you're doing so it's hard to judge. What happens if you remove all the channel stuff? Just handle the requests and skip SendDataToChannel. Does it behave the same? If so (which is my guess) then the problem is that you are overflowing your capacity.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer the server works fine without feeding and handle the channel. The sendDatatoChannel is more like a middleware in every request，would not affect server‘s regular logic . The handleData is a gorouting started before the server start.

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer One interesting thing is that， even if I remove Dosomething .The cpu still increase infinitly. So I think is something about the loop maybe

Comment: Well, your code doesn't reveal enough, remember the minimal reproducible example thing...

Comment: How does this even compile? You declare TestChan to be type int then assign a chan int to it. As far as I know that isn't allowed in Go.

Comment: @PatrickMahomes slip， edited

Comment: Need a minimal working example here. `SendDataToChannel` function doesn't make sense -- it is equally as writing `TestChan <- dataIn`. From the problem, I understand that there is a tight loop somewhere eating up CPU.

To drop messages on the floor it is possible to create a buffered channel and if it is full, then return early.

Comment: Sleeping before checking the channel seems unnecessary. `tmpData := <- TestChan` will block until there is data on `TestChan`. Channels were made for this. [Example](https://gist.github.com/schwern/921c17face323cc91317204383f6d222)

Comment: @bgnfu7re not really，In this case， the qps of Senddata is much  more than handle. Since  the Dosomething（call other downstream server）  in handle func is in a qps limitation， and the data which send to Senddata func can be discarded， I use select default in Senddata func and non-buffered channel.  Then using Sleep in Handle func to control the qps to downstream.

Comment: @Schwern plz see my case on reply bgnfu7re.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that when Add the Channel Logic, the logic will add some data to a place that other code in the server would frequently serialize/deserialize them. And thats the place which eat the CPU. 
As a result, the CPU increasing is nothing to do with the infinite Channel logic